# Bootstrap button text is not responsive

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
I tried many things to get the button text responsive, but it is not working.
Here's my html code

```
<button style="margin-top : 5px;" 
        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cd-admin-create-modal-btn" ng-disabled = "form.$invalid"
        ng-click="submitRouterDtls(router);">Submit
</button>
<button style="margin-top : 5px;" 
        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cd-admin-create-modal-btn"
        ng-click="cancelOperation();">Cancel
</button>
```

Here's my css code

```
.cd-admin-create-modal-btn {
     width: 5vw;
     margin: 0 1vw;
     font-size : 1.5vw;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: i thinks  some code and your question missing (full code)  ?

Comment: The `5vw` means 5% of the viewport width, so I guess that it what it’s doing. You could add a `min-width` based on pixels or ems so that the buttons won’t be too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```css
.cd-admin-create-modal-btn {
  min-width: 10vw;
 margin: 0 1vw;
 font-size : 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button style="margin-top : 5px;" 
                         type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cd-admin-create-modal-btn" ng-disabled = "form.$invalid"
                            ng-click="submitRouterDtls(router);">Submit
                        </button>
                        <button style="margin-top : 5px;" 
                            type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cd-admin-create-modal-btn"
                            ng-click="cancelOperation();">Cancel
                        </button>
```